# Please help me learn to get html elements to show

Tags: html, css

I've been at this for a while. I have goggled, I have tried everything I can think of but can't figure out why I can't get and "p" or "h3" to display inside my "li" or "a" tags. Can someone please take a look at what I have and tell me what I am doing wrong and what i need to do in order to get text to show in my boxes here? Any help would be much appreciated. Sorry for my formatting. SO wont let me edit.

```
*{ -moz-box-sizing: border-box; -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; box-sizing: border-box;}

.GreenBoxContainer{
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 920px;
    padding: 0px;
    background-color: black;
    font-size: 0;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 300px;
}

.GreenBox{
    border-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius: 12px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 12px; 
    display: inline-block;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
}

.box11{
    margin-right: 10px;
    background-color: white;
}
.box22{
    background-color: white;
}
.box33{
    margin-left: 10px;
    background-color: white;
}

/* Change gradient here: http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/ */
.GreenBoxLinks{
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid #dee8bc;
    border-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius: 12px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 12px; 
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    background: #ffffff; /* Old browsers */
}

/* Change gradient here: http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/ */
.GreenBoxLinks:hover{
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid #dee8bc;
    border-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius: 12px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 12px; 
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
}



p{
    position: absolute;
    color: black;
}


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<link rel=stylesheet href="boxes.css">
<body>

<ul class="GreenBoxContainer">
    <li class="GreenBox box11">
        <a class="GreenBoxLinks" href="#">
                <p>xcbvvcbbvcvc</p>
        </a>
    </li>

    <li class="GreenBox box22"><a class="GreenBoxLinks" href="#"></a></li>
    <li class="GreenBox box33"><a class="GreenBoxLinks" href="#"></a></li>
</ul>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! For this type of questions - it would be very helpful if you prepare a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't see `p` and `h` elements because you're setting the font size to 0:

> font-size: 0;

This is your same example with that one line commented: http://jsfiddle.net/avk44/1/

```
.GreenBoxContainer{
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 920px;
    padding: 0px;
    background-color: black;
    #font-size: 0;   <-------------------- REMOVE
    display: inline-block;
    height: 300px;
}
```

Comment: O man that sucks. I added that in earlier because it was fixing the extra padding from the inline-block. Thanks for the extra set of eyes and next time I will set up a fiddle

Comment: No problem, happens to all of us. Don't forget to accept the answer, so that it gets closed. Btw, try to establish ways of debugging. For example 1. leave only the html and see if all elements show up, 2. if all's ok - remove css blocks one by one until you find the one causing the issue 3. investigate the block line by line.